# Import selected columns from a CSV files to SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, data-import

I am trying to import data from a CSV file to a SQL Server 2008 table. Data upload is working, but I want to import only selected columns, not all, and add them to a a new table, of same no. of columns, using the wizard, but its not happening, the wizard is selecting all the columns.

So is it possible using wizard that I only import selected columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the Import / Export wizard, when you get to Select Source Tables and Views click on the button "Edit Mappings" on the bottom left of the screen. That opens column mappings screen; on the destination column select Ignore to remove the column you don't want to import.

Comment: That works in when importing from table, but when importing from CSV, even I ignore columns, still they are being imported.

Comment: Strange that works for me; but so does this method on the "Choose a Data Source" step of the wizard on click into the advanced tab highlight the column you are interested in and click the delete button below the list.

Comment: how can I do the same in myql `phpmyadmin` ? @u07ch

Answer (score 2):

Since most people searching this question in 2019 aren't going to be using SQL2008, I'll add this for SQL Server 2016:

When you choose your Flat File data source, there is an Advanced option to the left of the window.  Click that.

You will see a list of field names, and just below that there are 3 buttons.  One of them is Delete.

Highlight the field you do not want to include and click the Delete button.  Do this for all fields you do not wish to import.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. But, out of 10. I deleted first three and last four columns since I wanted to import 4th, 5th , and 6th columns only from csv file. The wizard took the values of the first three columns and displayed it under the  4th, 5th , and 6th columns. That, obviously is not what I wanted. What I was doing wrong? Is there anything I am missing here.

Comment: This is a separate issue, so should be submitted under a separate question.

Answer (score -2):

First Use same data type which declare in choose data source file. After choosing "destination file" go to edit mapping, and select "edit sql" and take only selected column and declare the same data type. edit mapping select Ignore which column you don't want and declare same data type.

Comment: if the question has a marked answer, please dont just write the same thing